# 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Capacity' - C#

Tags: c#

Can anybody help me to fix 2 mistakes, please?

In the **class Car** shows:

1. **this.persons = new Person[initialColor];**  -  "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'".
2. **for(int j = 0; j < persons.Capacity; j++)**  - 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Capacity' and no extension method
   'Capacity' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could
   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
   reference?)

Why there is no problem with: **for (int i = 0; i < cars.Length; i++)** ? But there is a problem with **.Capacity**. What I can use instead of  Capacity?

using System;

```
public class Program
    {   
        public static void Main()
        {
            Car blueCar = new Car("blue");
            Garage smallGarage = new Garage(2); 
            Person relativePerson = new Person("relative");


            smallGarage.ParkCar(blueCar, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(smallGarage.Cars);

            blueCar.SitPerson(relativePerson, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(blueCar.Persons);
        }
    }


    class Car
    {
        private Person[] persons;

        public Car(string initialColor)
        {
            Color = initialColor;
            this.persons = new Person[initialColor];
        }

        public string Color { get; private set; }

        public void SitPerson (Person person, int seat)
        {
            persons[seat] = person;
        }
        public string Persons
        {
            get
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < persons.Capacity; j++)
                {
                    if (persons[j] != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The {0} is in a {1} car.", persons[j].Type, j));
                    }
                }
                return "That's it.";
            }
        }
    }


    class Garage
    {
        private Car[] cars;

        public Garage(int initialSize)
        {
            Size = initialSize;
            this.cars = new Car[initialSize];
        }

        public int Size { get; private set; }

        public void ParkCar (Car car, int spot)
        {
            cars[spot] = car;
        }

        public string Cars 
        {
            get 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < cars.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (cars[i] != null)    
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The {0} car is in spot {1}.", cars[i].Color, i));
                    }
                }
                return "That's all!";
            }
        }
    }


    class Person
    {
        public Person(string initialType)
        {
            Type = initialType;
        }
        public string Type { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays) to learn how to use array

Comment: `Capacity` is a member of `List<T>`, not `Array`. `Capacity` should not be used to get the number of elements, it's an internal implementation detail, that's what `Length` is for.

Comment: As error message said, `System.Array` has not `Capacity` but `Length`. So you should use it.

Comment: Thanks! I changed Capacity to Length. It works.

Answer (score 1):

`Capacity` as it applies to extendable collections, such as [`List<T>.Capacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx), refers to the size of the underlying array; in C#, however, arrays are fixed width, so there's no conceptual difference between an array's Capacity and Length.

Under the hood, `List<T>` grows by copying the elements into newer, larger arrays as needed, necessitating `Capacity` almost exclusively for diagnostic purposes.

As for trying to initialize via `new Person[initialColor]`, you've used the wrong brackets: `[]` are for arrays and looking up items in arrays, `()` are for methods calls (and in this context, `new Person(initialColor)` is calling the constructor on `Person`).

Comment: I changed brackets and it shows next:   Cannot implicitly convert type 'OPP1.Person' to 'OPP1.Person[]'.    (OPP1 Person - is my namespace).

Comment: So, I did change the brackets:   this.persons = new Person(initialColor);  But there is still mistakes which I don't know how to fix: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'OPP1.Person' to 'OPP1.Person[]'"

Comment: @David also worth mentioning that `List<T>.Capacity` is [always greater or equal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) than `List<T>.Count`, meaning that if you have a `List<T>` with 5 elements, then `List<T>Capacity == 8` unless you call `List<T>.TrimExcess()`, which sets `List<T>.Capacity = List<T>.Count`. Should point explicitly that the proper way to get an `array` length is by the property `array.Length`